# Connect a Custom Text View to a TextView in IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create a custom textview it is possible to connect it to a textview created by IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, created the associated property and synthesize it using your new class. Then in IB, make sure you set UITextViews class under the Inspector -> Identity tab.